# How to use react-hook-form to change value in array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

**Used** : javascript with react, `react-hook-form` and `material-ui`

**Explanation** : I have one list with mutliple categories (DatasTest).
When the user checked an object in a categories, I add it in an array as an object with append from `react-hook-form` (working)
Now, I need to update specific value in the object added.

Here is my parent component with the list (DatasTest)

```js
    import { Box, Stack } from '@mui/material';
    import React from 'react';
    import { FormReusable, Test } from '../../reusable/FormReusable';
    import { useFieldArray } from 'react-hook-form';
    
    const users = [
      { engineer: 'user One', title: 'name One' },
      { engineer: 'user Two', title: 'name One' },
      { engineer: 'user Three', title: 'name Two' },
      { engineer: 'user Four', title: 'name Three' },
    
    ];
      
    
    const DatasTest = {
      AssesmentDatas: [
        { name: 'name One' },
        { name: 'name Two' },
        { name: 'name Three' },
        { name: 'name Four' },
      ],
      DesignDatas: [
         { name: 'name One' },
        { name: 'name Two' },
        { name: 'name Three' },
        { name: 'name Four' },
      ],
      ImplementationDatas: [{ name: 'Name Five' }],
    };
    
     
    export const ProjectType = ({ control, watch, register, replace }) => {
      return (
           <Test
            DatasTest={DatasTest}
            control={control}
            watch={watch}
            register={register}
            users={users}
            replace={replace}
          />
          
      );
    };
```

Then, Here is where i have my check box and input

```js
    export const Test = ({ DatasTest, control, watch, users, register }) => {
      const currentDate = new Date();
    
      const watchTest = watch('test');
    
      const { fields, append, prepend, remove, swap, move, insert, replace } =
        useFieldArray({
          control,
          name: 'test',
        });
    
    
      const handleCheckboxChange = ({ event, key, index, el }) => {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          append({
            labelName: key,
            name: el?.name,
            currentDate: currentDate,
            engineer: '',
            url: '',
          });
        } else {
          remove(index);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <Box>
          {JSON.stringify(watchTest)}
          {Object.keys(DatasTest).map((key) => (
            <div key={key}>
              <h2>{key}</h2>
              <ul>
                {DatasTest[key].map((el, index) => {
                  const filteredUsers = users?.filter((user) =>
                    user?.title.includes(el?.name)
                  );
    
                  return (
                    <Box>
                      <FormControlLabel
                        sx={{ width: '20%', margin: '1em 2em' }}
                        control={<Checkbox />}
                        onChange={(event) =>
                          handleCheckboxChange({ event, key, index, el })
                        }
                        label={el?.name}
                      />{' '}
    
                      <FormControl sx={{ width: '25%', margin: '1em 2em' }}>
                        <Select {...register(`test${[index]}.engineer`)}>
                          {filteredUsers?.map((user, index) => (
                            <MenuItem key={index} value={user?.engineer}>
                              {user?.engineer}
                            </MenuItem>
                          ))}
                        </Select>
                      </FormControl>{' '}
                    </Box>
                  );
                })}
              </ul>
            </div>
          ))}
        </Box>
      );
    };
```

What I have tried : I have tried to add '`register`' in my FormControl engineer and update it with `{...register(test${[index]}.engineer)}` but I got nothing (don't update the object)